# What UWP API raises a purchase event?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am creating a UWP video editor application centered on the MediaComposition class and I want the user to play with and test it for as long as they want as they would be granted an unlimited free trial upon downloading and installing it. (The app will be made available through the Windows Store.) However, any videos produced will have a watermark. The watermark will be removed as soon as they purchase the app.

What API will raise a purchase event to help me accomplish this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-in-app-product-purchases

Comment: Your question does not specify how you are licensing your application -- is it through the [tag:windows-store] or some third party technology like [tag:flexlm]?  Please [edit] your question to clarify and tag appropriately.

Comment: If through the [tag:windows-store] then maybe [`StoreContext.OfflineLicensesChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.offlinelicenseschanged?view=winrt-22000) is what you want? (Never tried it myself.)  Maybe also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/implement-a-trial-version-of-your-app or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#implement-trial.

Comment: All comments have been very helpful. Thank you all!

Comment: You're welcome.  The tag [tag:windows-store-apps] *refers to Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 apps only* so I went ahead and added [tag:windows-store].

Comment: @dbc Your comment is the correct way to implement an in-app-purchase feature. Would mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT - done.

Comment: @MPsyllakis - Your question was specifically about detecting the change in licensing which can be done as per the answer.  However, removing a watermark that has been already been burned into previously created videos seems... difficult.

Comment: Actually, there is no intention to remove a watermark from videos created during trial. Just to ensure that they won't be added once the license has been purchased. And this would be clearly stated as to not upset the user. Thank you for the full answer!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`StoreContext.OfflineLicensesChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.offlinelicenseschanged?view=winrt-22000) event from the [`Windows.Services.Store`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.offlinelicenseschanged?view=winrt-22000) to detect changes in your app's Microsoft Store license:

> **`StoreContext.OfflineLicensesChanged` Event**
>
> Raised when the status of the app's license changes (for example, the trial period has expired or the user has purchased the full version of the app).
>
> ```
> public event TypedEventHandler<StoreContext,object> OfflineLicensesChanged;
> ```
>
> When this event is raised, you can get the latest app license from the Microsoft Store by calling the [`GetAppLicenseAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.getapplicenseasync?view=winrt-22000#Windows_Services_Store_StoreContext_GetAppLicenseAsync) method. The [`StoreAppLicense`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense?view=winrt-22000) object returned by this method also contains the latest add-on licenses for the app in the [`AddOnLicenses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense.addonlicenses?view=winrt-22000#Windows_Services_Store_StoreAppLicense_AddOnLicenses) property.

However, note the following [version restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/implement-a-trial-version-of-your-app):

> The `Windows.Services.Store` namespace was introduced in Windows 10, version 1607, and it can only be used in projects that target Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393) or a later release in Visual Studio. If your app targets an earlier version of Windows 10, you must use the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store` namespace instead of the `Windows.Services.Store` namespace. For more information, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/exclude-or-limit-features-in-a-trial-version-of-your-app).

On earlier versions versions, the equivalent event is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.offlinelicenseschanged?view=winrt-22000#remarks) to be the [`LicenseChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.licensechanged?view=winrt-22000) event in the [`Windows.ApplicationModel.Store`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store?view=winrt-22000) namespace, which has the following additional remark:

> LicenseChanged events aren't always immediate. If you’ve registered for the event, the event should fire within an hour; if not, it should occur within 6 hours. Generally, it's recommended to wait up to 6 hours when testing with [`CurrentApp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp?view=winrt-22000), knowing that it will most likely take less time if the app has registered the event.

See also:

- [Implement a trial version of your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/implement-a-trial-version-of-your-app)
- [In-app purchases and trials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#implement-trial).
- [Exclude or limit features in a trial version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/exclude-or-limit-features-in-a-trial-version-of-your-app)